# How to count total number of person in a class

Tags: python

> class Person:
>       number_of_people = 0 #class atribute,define for the entire class
>
> ```
> def __init__(self,name):
>     self.name=name
> ```

```
p1 = Person('tim')  # adding of object to class
p2 = Person('jill')
p3 = Person('Bill')


for x in range(Person.number_of_people): #will loop 3 time this case
print(Person.name)  # how do i print all the names in a class
```

## i cant seem to get this working

Comment: Blockquote does not format code readably; in fact it breaks code by altering line breaks. See [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186/628368). I suggest you [edit] this question, delete the content, paste your code again, and this time format it as code.

Answer (score 0):

You could initialize a variable `NUMBER_OF_PEOPLE=0` outside your class declaration and then each time someone call `__init__` you can add one:

```py
class Person:
    # Declare class variables
    NUMBER_OF_PEOPLE = 0
    LIST_OF_PEOPLE = []
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        # Change the class variables
        Person.LIST_OF_PEOPLE.append(self)
        Person.NUMBER_OF_PEOPLE +=  1

    @classmethod
    def get_number_of_people(cls):
        return Person.NUMBER_OF_PEOPLE

p1 = Person("tim")
p2 = Person("jill")
people = [p1, p2]  # create a list o two people
# Iterate through the list
for p in Person.LIST_OF_PEOPLE:
    # Access the name by calling p.name
    print("Name of the current person is: {}.".format(p.name))
# You can still access the NUMBER_OF_PEOPLE variable either by calling Person.get_number_of_people() (since it is a class method) 
# or by simply using the NUMBER_OF_PEOPLE variable.
print("Currently, there are {} number of people in the class!".format(Person.get_number_of_people()))
# This will give 1 person.
```

Your issue here is that you don't completely understand object-oriented programming. You will get better by practising.

Comment: Hi ssry my question wast all the way do you mind loooking and helping again

Comment: okay check the new answer. the only change is that you now have a list of `Person` items and you can iterate through them.

Comment: people = [p1, p2]  # create a list o two people is there a way to add p3 for example with out manualy entering if lets say have alot of ppl

Comment: Hi sorry but i edited again 3rd time is it possible to for loop like this

Comment: You could iterate through the number of people: `for i in range(Person.get_number_of_people):` and inside the for block you can access an element by doing `print(people[i].name)` (getting the i-th element of the list).  If this answer is correct then mark the question as solved.

Comment: sry what i mean people = [p1,p2,p3] let say i gt p1 to p100 how do i loo[ to add or append into [   ] instead of manualy entering one at a time

Comment: by using the `append` method. E.g. `people.append(new_person_instance)`

Comment: hmm i know the append function but how to i appends [p1,p2,p3...p100] without manulally maybe a for loop or something but i cant seem to get something.Mayber like append every time init so first init [p1] then second init [p1,p2] automatically any ideas

Comment: okay check the updated answer. I added `LIST_OF_PEOPLE` and  I also changed the other variables to static.

Comment: ty will check when free

Comment: how does p.name know which p1 p2 p3 is it by the for loop

Comment: It doesn't know that and there is no reason for it to know it. If you definitely want it then you could provide an `id` in addition to the `name` variable. So, it is either this or the manual initialization of `people=[p1, p2, p3]`.

Comment: Ohi see p is based of the for loop interation. Person.LIST_OF_PEOPLE.append(self) why append(self) not name.

Comment: because you append the whole `Person` object and not just the name. If the `Person` class also had a variable `self.surname` then every element of `Person.LIST_OF_PEOPLE` will contain both `name` and `surname`.

Comment: print("Name of the current person is: {}.".format(p.surename)) if got sure name also what is .format thank you

Comment: `format` is a python3 function that allows you to use variables inside string. For example `name='tim'; print("The name is: {}".format(name))`. This will replace the `{}` with the value of the variable `name` (which is `tim`).

Answer (score 0):

You would need a global variable to keep track of each instance this way, but more likely you would define a parent class, like People, and then have your Person class inherit from People. People would instead be in charge of tracking how many Person instances you've created. The latter option would be best if you have to look at more than just this one relationship between your Person instances. If you wanted to iterate through your Persons, for example, that could be a methods of your People class.

Comment: Hi sry my question wast all the way do you mind loooking and helping again